# Question Regarding Vershynin's Proof of Bernstein's Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

I have been studying Vershynin's "High-dimensional Probability," and  I have some confusion regarding the proof of Bernstein's inequality (Thm 2.8.2). It concerns the following step: (Perhaps note that $(X_i)_i$ is a finite sequence of independent, mean zero subexponential random variables)

By a property of subexponential random variables, we can bound their MGF the following way for $|\lambda| \leq \frac{c}{\max \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}}$:

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp (\lambda X_i)] \leq \exp (C \lambda^2 \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}^2).$$

Thus we get (from a previous step, note $S := \sum X_i$)
$$ \mathbb{P}(S \geq t) \leq \exp (-\lambda t + C \lambda^2 \sigma^2) \quad (*)$$
where $\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}^2$. Now we minimize this expression in $\lambda$ with respect to the constraint and get an optimal choice of

$$\lambda = \min \left(\frac{t}{2C\sigma^2}, \frac{c}{\max_i \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}}\right).$$

Thus, with this we obtain
$$ \mathbb{P}(S \geq t) \leq \exp \left(-\min \left(\frac{t^2}{4C\sigma^2}, \frac{ct}{2 \max_i \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}}\right)\right).$$

Now, my issue is with this last step. I get how we get the first term in the minimum simply by plugging in the first possible value of $\lambda$ into (*), and I would think to get the second one I just have to plug in the second possible value, but I don't see how I then get the second value... am I missing something?

---

If you want to check the source material, the book is available online for free under

[https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)

Comment: Where does "$c$" appear (lowercase)? Is this a typo with $C=c$ intended?

Comment: @FShrike it's not a typo, $c$ and $C$ are two different positive absolute constants.

Comment: @FShrike If I am not mistaken, it should be the case that $C = \frac{1}{c^2}$, but I am not completely sure. This comes from the fact that the mentioned property of subexponential variables is $\mathbb{E}[\exp (\lambda X)] \leq \exp (K^2 \lambda^2 \|X\|^2)$ for $|\lambda| \leq \frac{1}{K}$ and holds for any value of $K$ that is within an absolute constant factor of $\|X\|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking this through with a friend, I think I have come up with an answer. Note that we can rewrite
$$ -\lambda t + C \lambda^2 \sigma^2 = -\lambda(t - C \lambda \sigma^2)$$
and
$$ t - C \lambda \sigma^2 = t - \min \left(\frac{t}{2}, \frac{cC\sigma^2}{\max \|X_i\|_{\phi_1}} \right) $$
when plugging in the optimal value for $\lambda$. Now, we can observe that the minimum above is less than or equal to $\frac{t}{2}$, and so
$$ \exp (-\lambda t + C \lambda^2 \sigma^2) \leq \exp (-\lambda \frac{t}{2}). \quad (**)$$
So, using this one gets the inequality above by now simply plugging in $\lambda$ in $(**)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac{t}{2 C \sigma^2} > \frac{c}{\max_i \Vert X_i \Vert_{\psi_1}} \iff \sigma^2 < \frac{t \max_i \Vert X_i \Vert_{\psi_1}}{2 cC}.$$
So if the optimal $\lambda = c / \max_i \Vert X_i \Vert_{\psi_1}$, we can use the above inequality for $\sigma^2$ in your equation $(*)$; simplifying yields the second case of the claimed probability bound as stated.